# multiple spline charts with multiple nested series highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts and trying to populate multiple spline charts and toggle them on one charts.

i need to toggle series starting with chart2 on one series called chart2 and toggle series starting with chart1 on another series called chart1.

(please check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukca9tcv/22/) to understand my point).

```
  series: [{
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'chart1-1',
  data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
}, {
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'chart1-2',
  data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
}, {
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'chart1-2',
  data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
}, {
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'chart2-1',
  data: [4, 3, 5, 3, 2]
}, {
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'chart2-2',
  data: [4, 3, 7, 2, 4]
}, {
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'chart2-3',
  data: [3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
}],
```

how can i achieve this type of nested series toggle.

also check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cst87q3s/24/) by using id and linkedTo property, but yet not fills requirement, because i need to combine both fiddles

```
 series: [
{
    id: 'Adwords',
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'Adwords',

},{
    linkedTo: 'Adwords',
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'click',
  data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
},
{
    linkedTo: 'Adwords',
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'Conver',
  data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
}, {
    linkedTo: 'Adwords',
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'Impr',
  data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
},{
    id: 'Bing',
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'Bing',

},{
    linkedTo: 'Bing',
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'click',
  data: [4, 3, 7, 2, 4]
},{
    linkedTo: 'Bing',   
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'Conver',
  data: [4, 3, 5, 3, 2]
}, {
    linkedTo: 'Bing',
  type: 'spline',
  name: 'Impr',
  data: [3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
}]
```

thanks,

Comment: Summarising, the goal is draw 3 series (chart2) and when you click on a legend item then series should be updated by chart1 values? Im a little bit confused what is on your purpose.

Comment: Use [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.events.legendItemClick) event to set visibility of the proper series. E.g. if the clicked item has the series which has the name chart1-1, you can check if chart1-* part the string is included in the other series name and toggle their visibility - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setVisible See the example http://jsfiddle.net/jp4wudt1/

Comment: i used linkedTo property to link series kindly check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cst87q3s/24/), but i also want to toggle individual series as well. in this[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cst87q3s/24/) there are only parent series showing by which other series are linked but i also want to show all child series and toggle them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for help, i got this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp4wudt1/21/), any suggestion for better will be thankful.